# uploading bundle in play store getting error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

Getting this error in play store console while uploading bundle in play store console

Manifest file code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smartbharat.one">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
   <application
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaSyDPzRxpT0mhrdEjTipEadB0l8T2tyu3m5E"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
        <activity
         android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
         android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy fix to this which is setting the max supported version with 30 instead of 31 in your build.gradle file/files

However to support 31:
From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12)

**If your app targets Android 12 or higher and contains activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must explicitly declare the android:exported attribute for these app components.
If the app component includes the LAUNCHER category, set android:exported to true. In most other cases, set android:exported to false.
**

```
<service android:name="com.example.app.backgroundService"
         android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.START_BACKGROUND" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

PS: I would suggest using the canary version of android studio and build your project because it's listing would show you the errors in the manifest.

Comment: did same problem cant upload play store

Comment: downgrade to 30?

Comment: yes         targetSdkVersion 30

Answer (score 3):

changing target sdk to 30 worked for me.

Comment: Man, you saved my day, I was trying to solve this problem for a looong time.

Comment: Google Play is now requries sdk min 31. So ıt's no longer work.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it one of your activities is not setting exported.

Replace

```
<activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

and

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
     android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

with

```
<activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:exported="true" />
```

and

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: getting same error

Comment: Sorry, I noticed you had 2 activities without it, answer is updated